# Java array input thorughnextInt()

Tags: java, inputstream

```
 import java.util.*;;

    public class selection {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    private int size;
    private int[] num=new int[size];

    selection(int size){
      this.size=size;
             }
    void enternum(){
        System.out.print("enter number"+size);
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
            num[i]=in.nextInt();

    }

    void sort(){
        for (int i=0;i<num.length;i++){
        int min=i;

        for(int j=i+1;j<num.length;j++){

                if(less(num[i],num[j]))
                    excg(i,j);
        }
    }

     display();

    }

    boolean less(int x,int y){
        if(x>y)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    void excg(int i,int j){

        num[i]=num[j];
        num[j]=num[i];
    }


    void display(){
        for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
            StdOut.println(num[i]);
    }

 public static void main (String[] arg){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("enter total num of the array");
        int size=in.nextInt();

        selection obj=new selection(size);
        obj.enternum();
        obj.sort();
    }
 }
```

when we enter the direct value of the size i.e size=5 then it is working but whenwe enter throughkey board then it is giving error aaray out of box .i am taking input through 
scanner class using nextInt() method

Answer (score 1):

That's because you allocate the array to be size 0.  If you allocate it after you read in the size, instead of *before*, then it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Initilize the array at the constructor. By deafult int class member(size) initialized with 0.

```
private int[] num;

selection(int size){
    //this.size=size;  //not required. 
    num=new int[size];
}
```